# Can't start coroutine for the second time

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines

I have wrote some coroutine, which will trigger ViewModel function to perform an api call. The coroutine is in `onCreateView` section.

The coroutine itself looks like this:

```
        val myCoroutine =
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView: ?")
            mViewModel.performApiCall()
            mViewModel.myLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { obj ->
                when (obj ) {
                    is DataWrapper.Success -> {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView: ${obj.data}")
                        
                    }

                    is DataWrapper.Error -> {
                        Log.e(
                            TAG,
                            "onCreateView: couldn't perform an api call ${obj.message}"
                        )
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

I'd like to start this coroutine, after user will click on button:

```
mBinding.conversionConverseBtn.setOnClickListener {
                myCoroutine.start()  
}
```

After first time, everything is working fine, but I've implemented `SwiperRefreshLayout`, and when I refresh the layout (by refresh I mean set UI as it was when user enter fragment) it doesn't work. I was loging almost every step, and it turns out that after refresh the myCoroutine is not active, and seems like it doesn't even starting when I call `.start()`. How I may solve it?

Comment: Your code doesn't have balanced parentheses -- it wouldn't compile.  Can you fix that?

Comment: coroutines can only start once and finish once. You can't recover or restart a completed coroutine. For API with that behavior use Flows.

Answer (score 2):

You can use getter in your code like this:

```
val myCoroutine: Job
get() = viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
    // Your code
}
```

Please note that you should instantiate `myCoroutine` as a variable in your class instead of within your `onCreateView` section. You can then call `myCoroutine.start()` as many times as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Coroutines can be started only once, you need to create new coroutine using `launch` to run it again, I would recommend to move the code to perform api call into a method and call it on refresh

```
fun fetchData(){
  viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
     mViewModel.performApiCall()
  }
}

fun onCreateView(){
  fetchData()
  mViewModel.myLiveData.
    observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { obj ->
         when (obj) {
             is DataWrapper.Success -> {
                 Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView: ${obj.data}")
             }
             is DataWrapper.Error -> {
                 Log.e(TAG, "onCreateView: couldn't perform an api call ${obj.message}")
             }
          }
     })
}
```